# prevent unathorized users to access public blob in WA

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have created a "public Blob" container. Our application can add files to this container. The problem is everyone can see the files (PDF files) if they know the url and browe to them.

What can we do to prevent unauthorized users to see these files? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent unauthorized access you will need to change the container back to **private**. That way, only people with a valid account/key combination or people with a valid SAS can access the blobs.

The SAS can be used in different ways: by using it in the SDK (if you want your client applications to use it) or by appending it to the URL of the blob.

Check out Maarten's blog post about SAS to get started: [Storing user uploads in Windows Azure blob storage](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2012/12/18/Storing-user-uploads-in-Windows-Azure-blob-storage.aspx)

Comment: We will test SAS and will be back to mark your answer as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Access Control for Azure Blobs:
http://convective.wordpress.com/2010/01/20/access-control-for-azure-blobs/